# Effect of multiple alloying elements on steel's eutectoid properties

Tags: steel, metallurgy, material-science

Mechanical engineering student here (the professor is not being helpful). When a single alloying element is added to a normal iron-carbon steel, the resulting changes in eutectoid temperature and composition are relatively easy to determine using graphs such as the following:

[image]

How would you predict the changes if multiple alloying elements were added instead of just one? I understand that some elements tend to stabilize ferrite versus austenite (you can tell by the relative slopes of the upper graph), but this only provides a qualitative answer. Is there any way to calculate exactly what the changes would be? Thanks.

---

<sub>Image source: https://www.tf.uni-kiel.de/matwis/amat/iss/kap_9/illustr/s9_2_1.html</sub>

Comment: There are methods such as DOE (Design of Experiments) that could help understand what their effect is on their properties. Although it doesn't answer your question it give you a nice means of seeing how such things can be represented.

Comment: That is why there are "hardenability" tables for most alloys. Look for a reference with "TTT" curves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effect of multiple alloy elements is not as simple as single elements. The addition of one element changes how the material interacts with another and each element combination has a different effect. Additions of Mn, for example, will change how much Ni or C the matrix can solubilize, and that should change the behavior of your upper plot.

You could qualitatively approach this problem, for example, by using Carbon Equivalent, Chromium Equivalent or Nickel Equivalent Formulae to understand different phase diagrams, like the Schaeffler Diagram, shown below.
[[image: Schaeffler Diagram, used primarily for study of stainless steels. Source: ][1]]

The method most used nowadays in alloy design and research is that of CALPHAD, or CALculation of PHAse Diagrams. Experimental data is modeled and chemical activity models calculate phase stability criteria, yielding exactly what your question tries to understand. Via a CALPHAD software (like Thermocalc), one could generate plots or tables to understand the effect of many different variables, including alloying elements.